# If $\cos2v = - \frac{1}{9}$ and $v$ is acute, then determine the value of $v$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\cos2v = - \dfrac{1}{9}$$
>   the angle $v$ is acute.
>
> Determine the value of $v$.

I have tried using the double angle identity $$ \cos2v = \cos^2v - \sin^2v $$ but I get a very complicated answer. I am almost certain that there must be a simpler way to solve this, since this question is labeled as "easy" in my textbook.

Comment: Sure, $\frac12\arccos(-\frac19)\approx 0.8410686705679302557765250318264307467$

Comment: Is $v = \arcsin x$ or something?

Comment: I've used $$ cos2v = cos^2v - sin^2v $$ but I get that $$ cos^2v = \frac{8}{18} $$ which I cant simplify..

Comment: @Synchrowave put the content of your last comment into your question, as your attempt. Otherwise will be the question closed. As for the cosine,  8/18=4/9 and you know that the angle is acute. Hence $\cos v=2/3.$

Comment: Also, fix your question - are you asking for $v$ or for $\cos v$?

Comment: Please why is this tagged *calculus*?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, we find 
$$
\cos^2 v = \frac{8}{18} = \frac{4}{9}
$$
Hence
$$
\cos v = \pm \frac{2}{3}
$$
To my (read: Google's) knowledge, no exact answer for $v$ that doesn't make use of $\cos^{-1}$ is known. You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals) for a fairly extensive list of known exact trig  and inverse trig values.

Lacking an exact answer, the best we can do is the answer NoChance has already given.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Solving:
$$\cos(2x) = - \dfrac{1}{9}$$

For the general case, let the R.H.S constant be $k$. We'll use Radians.

You could apply $arccos$ function.

The definition of $arccos(x)$ is:
$$arccos(x)=\pm cos^{-1}(x)+2\pi n$$

and solve 2 equations for $x$ as follows:

$$2x=\cos^{-1} \left(k\right)+2\pi n \Rightarrow x=\frac{\cos^{-1}\left(k\right)+2\pi n}{2} \tag1$$
$$2x=-\cos^{-1} \left(k\right)+2\pi n \Rightarrow x=\frac{-cos^{-1}\left(k\right)+2\pi n}{2} \tag2$$

You may now use the fact the desired angle is acute (An Acute Angle is less than 90°).

[Ref: Precalculs with Trig.](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=Q9h_pgZl_6kC&pg=PA169&dq=solve%20using%20arccos%20inverse%20cos-1&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig8vTOnrXkAhUImhQKHVnvBA0Q6AEIPzAD#v=onepage&q&f=false)